# Display a phone number formatted in a formula field?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have a formula field, which displays a phone number. But I'm having some issues getting the number to display correctly. Its showing up as "6678894949", when I'm looking for something like "(812)-547-1458". Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try yourselves? What doesn't work? Also: title "look at he below for phone foramtt?" could use some rework...

Comment: Are these always US numbers, or do you need support for international formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
"(" & LEFT(Phone__c, 3) & ") - " & LEFT(RIGHT(Phone__c, 7), 3) & " - " & RIGHT(Phone__c, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula field with formula as below:

```
"(" + LEFT( Phone__c, 3) + ")-" + MID(Phone__c, 4, 3) + "-" + MID(Phone__c, 7, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula field supporting US numbers only.

```
LEFT(Phone, 4) & ") " & LEFT(RIGHT(Phone, 8), 3) & " - " & RIGHT(Phone, 4)
```